# ACPI Warnings in Debian 8 on ASUS EEEPC 1018P power crashes

Tags: debian, acpi

running mesg appears the following warnings:

```
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000800-0x000000000000087F (\PMIO) (20140424/utaddress-254)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F (\_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.IELK.GPSE) (20140424/utaddress-254)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000004B0-0x00000000000004BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000480-0x00000000000004BF (\_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.GPBX) (20140424/utaddress-254)
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000480-0x00000000000004AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000480-0x00000000000004BF (\_SB_.PCI0.SBRG.GPBX) (20140424/utaddress-254)
lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
```

I have a problem with the battery, it's seems that is fully loaded but suddendly the machine turns off.